# modify Pattern to check URL

Tags: php, regex

This function does not recognize a URL with a Number after the www

Example:

```
www.24storetogo.com
```

And I don't know how to modify it.

```
function isurl($get){

    $pattern = '/^https?:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+:[^\s@:]+@)?((([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z\-]+)|((2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|[01][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|[01][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|[01][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|[01][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})))(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/[!~*\'\(\)a-zA-Z0-9;\/\\\?:\@&=\+\$,%#\._-]*)*$/';

    $get=str_replace("\n", "", $get);
    if ($get=="" || !preg_match($pattern, $get)){$get='';}
    return $get;
}
```

Please help me on this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this..

```
^https?:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+:[^\s@:]+@)?((([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z\-]+)|((2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|[01][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|[01][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|[01][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|[01][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})))(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/[!~*\'\(\)a-zA-Z0-9;\/\\\?:\@&=\+\$,%#\._-]*)*$
```

<kbd>[Working Demonstration](http://regex101.com/r/gS0pY8)</kbd>